# Optimize SQL Statement: Select multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I would like to decrease my SQL querys. Here you can see an example of my table:
[image]

This statement returns me the amount of fields (0-3) I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(meta_key) FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` Where meta_key like 'product_shops_%_price' AND (post_id = 7951)
```

In this case I get a 4. So I have values from the field 0 to 3. For each number I need `product_shops_%_price`, `product_shops_%_price_old`, `product_shops_%_shop` and `product_shops_%_link`. So, 4 * 4 = 16 values.
Now I want to reduce my query from 4 to 1 query. Previously I asked every 4 fields separated. So I got 4 values for 0, for values for 1, and so an..

My Plan Now is the optimize that SQL Statement and Select all 16 values at once. Does anyone has a plan how I can do that?

And further, it would be very nice if I can pack all values which contains a 0 in a array, all which contains a 1 in a array and so on... So I can iterate through them easily.

I would be very grateful about help!
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this return what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` pm 
WHERE meta_key like 'product_shops_%' AND 
      post_id = 7951;
```

EDIT:

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` pm 
WHERE meta_key regexp '^(product_shops)_(link|price|price_old|shop)$' AND 
      post_id = 7951;
```

You can also do this with separate `like` expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` pm 
WHERE post_id = 7951 AND
      (meta_key like 'product_shops_%_price' OR 
       meta_key like 'product_shops_%_link' OR 
       meta_key like 'product_shops_%_price_old' OR 
       meta_key like 'product_shops_%_shop'
      );
```

Comment: No. There are a lots of other values with `product_shops_0_...`. So I only need those 4 different kinds of fields!

Comment: Yeah, that works. And my further question is, how can I iterate trough all values in PHP and but each value in one array where the numbers of the fields matches?

Comment: @FrazeJr. . . . You should ask that question with the PHP tag, because it is specifically about PHP code.